# Pass and update State Value from other function Flutter Hook Widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-hooks

I am new to Flutter hooks and I have requirements that I have to use HookWidget instead of StatefulWidget. As I know, useState can only be declared within the build function.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final selectedBook = useState("");
    return Container(
       child: _buildBookListContainer(context)
    )  
}

Widget _buildBookListContainer(BuildContext context) {
  //I will want to update the state value or read the state value in the child function
  //how do I do that?
  //Example: selectedBook.value = "xxx";
}
```

I tried passing down the state value as function arguments but it will not work. May I know that is it all HookWidget class will just write all components inside the build function without refractoring?

Comment: hello did you find anything about this?

Answer (score 0):

Presuming you're using Riverpod, watch my relatively short "building the counter app from scratch with my riverpod starter kit" at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0lPzFS5CAPs.  It shows how to create a StateProvider, and then either reference it (with listen) or update it (no listen) for precise control of widget rebuilds.